How to reliably clone and update (pull) a repo repeatedly in an automated pipeline?
Problem: I'm building a pipeline to do stuff in a git repo whenever there's a push (need to be able to do stuff like git diff or git merge-base). The repo takes forever to clone so instead of re-cloning every time at the beginning of the pipeline I want to have the repo persistently cloned and just do a checkout of the respective branch/tag/revision and a pull to start with a current version at each run, and in an idempotent manner.
I got the repo cloned but for the life of me I can't get the checkout/pull working right. Here's what I've tried:
Without a checkout:
+ git pull --recurse-submodules=no
From https://my.repo.url
 * [new branch]          20230110-test-37654     -> origin/20230110-test-37654
etc...
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

This actually successfully pulled new updates but returns a non-zero exit code.
So I tried a basic check out:
+ git checkout master
git checkout master returns an error error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

With --track:
+ git checkout --track master
fatal: missing branch name; try -b

Ok I'll use -b.
+ git checkout --track -b origin/master
fatal: a branch named 'origin/master' already exists

I'll try -B.
+ git checkout --track -B master
warning: not setting branch 'master' as its own upstream

Maybe that's the local branch name?
+ git checkout --track -B origin/master
branch 'origin/master' set up to track 'origin/dev'

At least it didn't fail this time. I suspect I was already on the dev branch or something? But I just wanted to switch to master, obviously I don't want master to track dev.
I also tried the --set-upstream-to option which seems to have worked but for some reason my branch diverged even though I haven't made any local commits--I've only done basically git clone, git checkout, git pull.
+ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 13252 different commits each, respectively.
+ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.
+ git pull --recurse-submodules=no
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.

Or this:
+ git checkout -B master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
+ git pull --recurse-submodules=no
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

I'm not good with git other than the basic stuff so if someone could help me figure out what commands I could use to reliably do like a checkout (that'll work with branches, tags, individual commits, etc) and pull every time the pipeline runs (without creating diverging branches or whatnot), I'd appreciate it.

Git commands like git diff (in many cases) and git merge-base do not need a checkout. Use git fetch instead of git pull.

adding to ElpieKay's comment: git fetch will do the "download the new content from remote" part. If you need to checkout a specific branch or commit, you can run git checkout [branch_or_commit] excplicitly afterwards, possibly with the -B option.

The option -b and -B creates a new branch. Do you really want to create the master branch (again) with git checkout -b/-B master. I assume no. Also the --track option is maybe not want you want.

You can switch to master simply with git checkout master. Then pull changes git pull. Then (if needed) create a new branch from the master git checkout -B pipeline_12344.

@mr.wolle @LeGEC git checkout master returns an error error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

@mr.wolle this pull is ran in a CI pipeline as a result of a repo push. So the branch may OR may not exist--I need to find a way to pull whether it does or doesn't.

@mr.wolle also with git checkout -B master I still get the error There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. when I pull

@LeGEC I stand corrected--I've been doing git checkout first then git pull, but from your recommendation, a git fetch then git checkout worked!
